# Trying to convert longitude/latitude to Cartesian coordinates

Tags: python, cartesian, polar-coordinates

i am trying to convert a city's longitude/latitude position to Cartesian so i can then convert it to pixel position to display on a pygame screen, but i am having trouble figuring it out.

```
def ConvertPoint(self, Long, Lat, height, width):
    self.x = Long
    self.y = Lat
    self.x = angleToPointX(self.x, self.y, 3959)
    self.y = angleToPointY(self.x, self.y, 3959)
    pygame.draw.circle(self.window, (255,0,0), (int(self.x), int(self.y)), 5)
    print(self.x, self.y)
```

functions:

```
def angleToPointX(lat, long, magnitude=1.0):
    V = (math.cos(lat) * math.cos(long))
    return V

def angleToPointY(lat, long, magnitude=1.0):
    V = (math.sin(lat))
    return V
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting from longitude\latitude to Cartesian coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates)

Comment: Like Lev said, what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is that once i do the conversion what should the magnitude be to multiply it by

Comment: In your angleToPoint functions, which are suspect to begin with, so regardless of lat/long passed in, your return values are going to be very small (-1 to +1 range). Try multiplying the return value by something like the pixel width of the area you're trying to position the cities in.  But be aware that your angleToPointX gives you a very unusual choice of projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What [map projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections) are you using? Latitude/longitude can be used directly as y/x in a cylindrical projection - that's the simplest way to go for a game. Otherwise, the conversion will be entirely dependent on the choice of projection.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar problems in the past and [this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) is what helped me through it