# X/Y/Z to Latitude/Longitude for Google Maps

Tags: maps, coordinates

I'm trying to convert X/Y/Z coords to Latitude/Longitude coords so I can plot them on a Google Map, but math not being my strongest subject I'm having trouble.

Could anyone help me with the conversion? or is there a way to plot X/Y/Z directly onto Google Maps?

Thanks

Comment: Reverse of this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates

Comment: @Tempster102 can you please post some code related to this question how you get that functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lat = asin(z / R) //Latitude
lon = atan2(y, x) //Longitube
```

Where R is the approx [radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius) of earth.

[Here's](http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/conversion-between-spherical-and-cartesian-coordinates-systems/) link to really simple & clear explaination of it.

Comment: What measurement would the radius of the earth be in? I used '6372797.560856' which is meters but it returns NAN for the value.             X: -8.85107925999806E+16 Y:4.23694439668789E+16 Z: -4.45135253464797E+160.9

Comment: @BrandonSmith unit of X,Y,Z & R should be same.(i.e Km or m Doesn't matter).

Comment: @BrandonSmith try R=6372797E-6 meters.

Comment: Z = -5.05854617976782E+16 / 6372797E-6 = asin(-7.9377174257517E+15) = PHP NAN (Not a Number)

Comment: @BrandonSmith Ex: 10 to the power 100 = 10^100 = 1E100. are you getting what I am trying to say? Convert those X, Y, Z, R to numbers get rid of 'E'

Comment: No :( Sorry, math is my worst area.

Comment: @BrandonSmith   post values of X, Y, Z you have in your question

Comment: X: -8.85107925999806E+16 Y:4.23694439668789E+16 Z: -4.45135253464797E+160.9 --- These values were pulled from a data dump, so this is the way the came when I imported them into my database.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16520/discussion-between-amandeep-jiddewar-and-brandon-smith)