# Convert X, Y in EPSG:2180 to

Tags: delphi, gis, geo

i have shape file (**.shp**) with data in **EPSG:2180**.
I have extracted positions like this one:

```
303553.0249270061 580466.2644065879
```

Same values i see in equivalent .gml file.
That i am sure values are ok.

**But how can i convert it to Latitude and Longitude?**
(from comments GPS is WGS 84 (a.k.a. EPSG:4326)).

i see that params about **EPSG:2180**:

```
latitude_of_origin=0
central_meridian=19
scale_factor=0.9993
false_easting=500000
false_northing=-5300000
SPHEROID = 6378137,298.257222101
degree=0.0174532925199433
```

I have tried such simple calculation like

```
one_degree = 111196.672; //meters
X:= 303553.0249270061;
Y:= 580466.2644065879;

X:= X - false_northing;
Y:= Y - false_easting;

X:= latitude_of_origin + X/one_degree;
Y:= central_meridian + Y/one_degree;
```

but this show me:

```
50.3931720629823
19.7236391427847
```

which is not true. It is near but should be >20.

How this calculation should looks like?
I need it in Delphi application.

Comment: You have not said to which coordinate system you wants to translate. Have you checked with this site: http://pacificprojections.spc.int/transform#s_srs=2180&t_srs=4326&x=303553.0249270&y=580466.2644066

Comment: i say to Latitude and Longitude and i need to know how, i need calculation in my application, not external site

Comment: I suggested the external site for you to check the values you have and to see you can convert them to many different coordinate systems. This site also give the details for each coordinate systems. Once you have the details, probably you can design Delphi computation. I cannot help more before you tell us to which coordinate system you want to convert and you used the site I mentioned to verify it gives the result you expect.

Comment: Maybe this other question/answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740192/overview-for-converting-local-plane-coordinates-to-wgs84

Comment: @fpiette i need Latitude and longitude like GPS or like it is on google map.
I have supposed that Latitude and Longitude is only one system and cannot be more. If i am wrong than please fix me.

Comment: GPS uses [WGS 84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#WGS84) (a.k.a. EPSG:4326).

Comment: updated ticket according comments. 
I also found some hint in source code of Proj4. Maybe i will convert it to Delphi. https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/releases

Comment: Or if you prefer Java to JavaScript, convert https://proj.org/ to Delphi.

Comment: There is site for converting from one system to another: https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=2180&t_srs=4326

Answer (score 0):

I **don't know** solution for You in **Delphi** but i found one in **js** and **php**.

I found this topic while i was searching *"how to transform location units from one system to another"* and google **EPSG:2180 convert**.

---

This problem name is:

***Transform a point coordinate from one map projection to another***

So solution is to make **mathematical transformation** and maby other calculations. You can Check:

**[Proj4 Library](https://live.osgeo.org/en/overview/proj4_overview.html)** 
with *API Interfaces: C, C++, Python, Java, Ruby*

My solution was to use library **[Proj4js](http://proj4js.org/)**.

Maby try to open source's on github of this library and analize function transform and with luck You will find answer ; )

---

I used php version of this package => **[Proj4jsphp](https://github.com/proj4php/proj4php)**

My problem was how to transform Coordinates in **EPSG:2180** => GPS is WGS 84 (a.k.a. **EPSG:4326**).

Later i found out there are different names for this systems:

**EPSG:2180 responds to Poland CS92**

**EPSG:4326 responds to WGS84** -> where WGS84 is the most popular system  (lat, lon).

---