# Angular: Converting number to WGS84 format

Tags: javascript, angular, coordinates, wgs84

I´m looking for a solution to convert coordinates. Is there any pipe | service | function by which I am able to convert numbers to WGS84 format? Thank you very much for any help.

```
Longitude: 11.111111
Latitude: 22.22222
```

Comment: Do you mean to convert to DMS (Degrees Minutes Seconds), e.g. N 22° 13.333200 E 11° 6.666660 ?

Comment: More like this WG+some number (WG+1111111) so the whole number would have the WG+ prefix, but there would be no ° included in the number.

Comment: but I know that there needs to be some calculation done for transforming 11.111111 to WG+1111111, just that I haven´t found any solution that I could apply

Comment: I looked, and i find no reference of WG+, Do you mean Google World coordinates? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/coordinates

Comment: Hmm, there is written in the first point that Google uses World Geodetic System WGS84, which I´m aiming for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overview for converting local plane coordinates to WGS84](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740192/overview-for-converting-local-plane-coordinates-to-wgs84)

Comment: There are 3 formats for the display of the WGS84 coordinates. Which one do you ask about? (1) Decimal degree (WGS84): `N 11.11111111 E 22.2222222222`. (2) Degrees Minutes (WGS84): `N 11° 6.666667 E 22° 13.333333`. (3) Degrees Minutes Seconds (WGS84): `N 11° 6' 39.999996 E 22° 13' 20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of converting to Degree, Minutes, Seconds (DMS). Once you have this you can then add the degree, minutes, and seconds signs if you prefer. You can also position the letters (NSWE) before or after the output string.

```js
function toDMS(LAT,LNG) {
const toDMS=coord=>{min=~~(minA=((a=Math.abs(coord))-(deg=~~a))*60);
return deg+" "+min+" "+Math.ceil((minA-min)*60);
};
return `${toDMS(LAT)} ${LAT>=0?"N":"S"} / ${toDMS(LNG)} ${LNG>=0?"E":"W"}`;
}

// examples
console.log(toDMS( 22.22222, 11.11111));
console.log(toDMS( -22.22222, -11.11111));
```

##### Another format would be like this:

```js
function toDMS(LAT,LNG) {
const toDMS=coord=>{min=~~(minA=((a=Math.abs(coord))-(deg=~~a))*60);
return deg+"° "+min+"' "+Math.ceil((minA-min)*60)+'"';
};
return `${LAT>=0?"N":"S"} ${toDMS(LAT)} / ${LNG>=0?"E":"W"} ${toDMS(LNG)}`;
}

// examples
console.log(toDMS( 22.22222, 11.11111));
console.log(toDMS( -22.22222, -11.11111));
```