# Convert CLLocation or CLLocationCoordinate2D to CGPoint

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocation, cgpoint

How can I convert `CLLocation` or `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to `CGPoint`.
I have seen

```
CGPoint point = [mapView convertCoordinate:myCoordinates toPointToView:self.view];
```

But I don't need to use `mapView` in my case. I tried googling, but didn't come across anything helpful.

Edit:
I need to convert the geographic coordinates to iPad's screen coordinate as in [Convert decimal latitude/longitude coordinates to iPad screen coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124171/convert-decimal-latitude-longitude-coordinates-to-ipad-screen-coordinates).
I am trying to draw line/path based on the converted coordinate values.

Is there a direct way to do it, or do I need to write an algorithm to do the same.

Comment: If you don't need to use mapView then why do you need to convert  coordinate to CGPoint?

Comment: No other way except using a map view.

Comment: I get current coordinates from `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations`.

Need to draw a path based on that on a view. No maps here.

Comment: check this out:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124171/convert-decimal-latitude-longitude-coordinates-to-ipad-screen-coordinates

Comment: I'm not sure that , Possible to get it without MapView..? . But I'll give some idea but this should be **STUPID idea** - Load the Mapview and HIDE It and get the CGPoint by using the Method You mentioned ...

Comment: Why down voting? Any suggestions to improve the question are welcome.

Comment: For convert CLLocationCoordinate2D to CGPoint see answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/37276779/2697425

Answer (score 9):

```
CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(coordinate.longitude, coordinate.latitude);
```

Note that the axes are swapped. But unless you give a coordinate system that you want the coordinate converted to, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I need to convert the geographic coordinates to iPad's screen coordinate as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124171/convert-decimal-latitude-longitude-coordinates-to-ipad-screen-coordinates.
I am trying to draw line/path based on the converted coordinate values.

Comment: Find the bounding box of all the coordinates, then normalize for the screen bounds (something like subtract the minimum values of latitude and longitude from all, divide by max, multiply by screen size).

Comment: So the above conversion wont suit my requirements.