# implement fog(blur) in map

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

i will try to last some days but not getting any idea to how can i solve this.here are some screenshot

when first time screen display than only userlocation is display in map and other map is blur but when user can move to another position than clear each position blur effect like my second screenshot

[image]

[image]

please give me some logic how can i solve this.

Comment: Very interesting. First you need to have a UIView covering up your Map, You need to use CLLocationManager for location updates, now translate location coordinate to the UIView pixels which will give you position of current location according to coordinates, when you get the point you need to erase the view with a radius around point just like a paint brush works. This problem has very long answer I just gave an idea you can start by this idea.

Comment: @iphonic hmm nice idea but how can i get UIView pixels point if possible give me some hint code

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16125211/790842