# How to Pass Locations From CLLocationManager

Tags: iphone, ios

How to Pass latitude and Longitude values form CLLocation Manager to My CustomView. I have A ViewController With CLLocationManger where iam getting the Locations, I have Another UIView Class with drawRect Where i have Divided the View with Coordinates as

```
#define EARTH_RADIUS 6371

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGPoint latLong = {41.998035, -116.012215};

    CGPoint newCoord = [self convertLatLongCoord:latLong];

    NSLog(@"Cartesian Coordinate: (%f, %f)",newCoord.x, newCoord.y);

    //Draw dot at coordinate
    CGColorRef darkColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:21.0/255.0
                                            green:92.0/255.0
                                             blue:136.0/255.0
                                            alpha:1.0] CGColor];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, darkColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(newCoord.x, newCoord.y, 100, 100));

}

-(CGPoint)convertLatLongCoord:(CGPoint)latLong
{
    CGFloat x = EARTH_RADIUS * cos(latLong.x) * cos(latLong.y);
    CGFloat y = EARTH_RADIUS * cos(latLong.x) * sin(latLong.y);

    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}
```

I have Took the  CGPoint latLong = {41.998035, -116.012215} static.

Can you say me How to Pass A ViewController Values to UIView Class

Answer (score 0):

You would generally have a property in you `UIView` subclass for your coordinate (either using your `CGPoint` or perhaps a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`) and then call `setNeedsDisplay` so that the device knows that it needs to call your `drawRect` method.

Thus, have a property:

```
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

And then update the implementation of your view as such:

```
- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    _coordinate = coordinate;

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGPoint newCoord = [self convertLatLongCoord:self.coordinate];

    NSLog(@"Cartesian Coordinate: (%f, %f)",newCoord.x, newCoord.y);

    //Draw dot at coordinate
    CGColorRef darkColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:21.0/255.0
                                            green:92.0/255.0
                                             blue:136.0/255.0
                                            alpha:1.0] CGColor];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, darkColor);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, darkColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(newCoord.x, newCoord.y, 100.0, 100.0));
}

// I assume you're using the algorithm from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1185413/1271826

- (CGPoint)convertLatLongCoord:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    CGFloat x = EARTH_RADIUS * cos(coordinate.latitude * M_PI / 180.0) * cos(coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180.0);
    CGFloat y = EARTH_RADIUS * cos(coordinate.latitude * M_PI / 180.0) * sin(coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180.0);

    // TODO: The above calculates x and y values from -EARTH_RADIUS to EARTH_RADIUS.
    // You presumably want to scale this appropriately for your view. The
    // specifics will vary based upon your desired user interface.

    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}
```

Then, when you want to update your view, you can do something like:

```
myCustomView.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.998035, -116.012215);
```

While I've tried to remedy some flaws in `convertLatLongCoord`, it's still not perfect, as it will yield values ranging from `-EARTH_RADIUS` to `EARTH_RADIUS` (which obviously won't work for a `CGRect` of a `UIView`, which is expecting values between zero and the width/height of the view).

I assume the underlying algorithm is one like discussed here: [Converting from longitude\latitude to Cartesian coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates/1185413#1185413). I've tried to fix the degrees to radians conversion needed by `cos` and `sin`, you still need to scale this and translate it to values appropriate for what portion of the map/radar you're intending to show.

Comment: I want to Update the Location as the Device Moves. its Without map.

Comment: @rajesh.k - Understood, but I don't think that `convertLatLongCoord` will achieve whatever you think it does. Play around with it and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Check this, i want to locate the boat without map.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.terboel.myanchorwatch

Comment: How to Draw Continuous line Connecting Locations on UIView

Comment: Ok, but your algorithm has two problems: First, you need to convert your latitude an longitude to radians (e.g. `coordinate.latitude * M_PI / 180.0`). To use radian based `cos` and `sin` functions with latitude and longitudes measured in degrees will not render the result you're looking for. Second, even if you do that, you'll get values ranging from `-EARTH_RADIUS` to `EARTH_RADIUS`. So you have to scale that to coordinates appropriate for your view.

Comment: Yes Thanks, Can you say me Please How to do it..?

Comment: @rajesh.k Seems like simple algebra to me: First, you need to know the range of cartesian coordinates to be shown by the view. Let's say you have a `CGRect` of cartesian coordinates of the current view called, say `viewCartesianRect`. Then, second, you could probably calculate the `x` and `y` coordinates on the view of some given the `CGPoint` cartesian coordinates of the point being considered, e.g. `pointCartesian`, and the resulting view coordinates would be `(pointCartesian.x - viewCartesian.origin.x) / viewCartesian.size.width * self.frame.width` (and repeat that for the height).

Comment: @rajesh.k If this is not obvious, I'd suggest that you (a) consider accepting my answer by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer (as I think I've answered the original question); and (b) you post a new question with your cartesian mapping question, as that's very different topic from your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment that you want to "find your boat" it sounds like you want the heading from your current location to a specified location (your boat).  That calculation is this

```
+ (float)getHeadingForDirectionFromCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)fromLoc toCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)toLoc
{
    float fLat = degreesToRadians(fromLoc.latitude);
    float fLng = degreesToRadians(fromLoc.longitude);
    float tLat = degreesToRadians(toLoc.latitude);
    float tLng = degreesToRadians(toLoc.longitude);

    float degree = radiansToDegrees(atan2(sin(tLng-fLng)*cos(tLat), cos(fLat)*sin(tLat)-sin(fLat)*cos(tLat)*cos(tLng-fLng)));

    if (degree >= 0) {
        return degree;
    } else {
        return 360+degree;
    }
}
```