# How we can convert the Longitude and Latitude in points

Tags: ios, android-mapview

I m working to get the Longitude and Latitude for current place and i m using the code

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
    int minutes = decimal * 60;
    double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"",
                     degrees, minutes, seconds];
    NSLog(@" Current Latitude : %@",lat);

    degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
    minutes = decimal * 60;
    seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
  //  longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"",
                //       degrees, minutes, seconds];

    longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"",
             degrees, minutes, seconds];
    NSLog(@" Current Longitude : %@",longt);

}
```

and getting the:

Current Latitude : 37° 47' 9.0024"
 Current Longitude : -122° 24' 23.1012"

But i want the Latitude and Longitude like that  13.233233 (mean in points). So how i can convert this in Longitude and Latitude in point ?Please help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "points"?

Comment: Mean in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: In Cartesian coordinates of what coordinate system?  The UIView or the MKMapView?  What's the purpose?  If you just want to display them in decimal format, do `NSLog(@"lat,long = %f,%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);`.  Also, this is not an "android-mapview".

Answer (score 0):

why are you using this depreciated method use this method for getting location in iOS 7. Use this method

```
 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

    {
   // location_updated = [locations lastObject];    
   // NSLog(@"updated coordinate are %@",location_updated);

    float currentLocationLati = [[locations objectAtIndex:0] coordinate].latitude;
        float currentLocationLong = [[locations objectAtIndex:0] coordinate].longitude;

    }
```

By this methods you will find update latitude and longitude just use them don't convert them into degree

Comment: this is an array of updated location, I update my answer you can get latitude and longitude in float from there

Answer (score 0):

From the following answer [Converting from longitude\latitude to Cartesian coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates/1185413#1185413)

```
x = R * cos(lat) * cos(lon)
y = R * cos(lat) * sin(lon)
z = R *sin(lat)
```

Where R is the approximate radius of earth (e.g. 6371KM).

Answer (score 0):

In newLocation.coordinate.latitude and newLocation.coordinate.longitude, you have the values you want, just don't convert them.