# Translate from X, Y, Z to Latitude and Longitude

Tags: javascript, geometry, mapping, geospatial

This is not a dupe of [Converting from longitude\latitude to Cartesian coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates).

I want to have functions that will translate back and forth between X, Y, Z coordinates and Latitude and Longitude.  The things is the application already has this function to go from latitude/longitude to XYZ (this function is not changeable)...

```
export function getXYZ(lat, lng, radius) {
  radius = radius || 200;

  var gamma = ( 90 - lat) * Math.PI / 180;
  var theta = (180 - lng) * Math.PI / 180;

  var x = radius * Math.sin(gamma) * Math.cos(theta);
  var y = radius * Math.cos(gamma);
  var z = radius * Math.sin(gamma) * Math.sin(theta);

  return {x: x, y: y, z: z};
}
```

I tried to create a paired function to go back the other way, but there's something not right.

```
export function getLatLng(vector, radius) {
  radius = radius || 200;

  var lat, latRads, lng, lngRads;

  latRads = Math.acos(vector.y / radius);
  lngRads = Math.atan2(vector.z, vector.x);

  lat = (Math.PI / 2 - latRads) * 180 / Math.PI;
  lng = (Math.PI - lngRads) * 180 / Math.PI;

  return [lat, lng];
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: Why doesn't the second answer at the linked question answer your question?

Comment: The difference with the other thread is that it assumes: (1) the x-axis goes through long,lat (0,0), (2) the y-axis goes through (0,90) and (3) the z-axis goes through the poles.  That is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just go ahead and answer my own question...

```
export function getLatLng(vector, radius) {
      radius = radius || 200;

      var latRads = Math.acos(vector.y / radius);
      var lngRads = Math.atan2(vector.z, vector.x);
      var lat = (Math.PI / 2 - latRads) * (180 / Math.PI);
      var lng = (Math.PI - lngRads) * (180 / Math.PI);

      return [lat, lng - 180];
    }
```

And the other way around...

```
 export function getXYZ(lat, lng, radius) {
      radius = radius || 200;

      var latRads = ( 90 - lat) * Math.PI / 180;
      var lngRads = (180 - lng) * Math.PI / 180;

      var x = radius * Math.sin(latRads) * Math.cos(lngRads);
      var y = radius * Math.cos(latRads);
      var z = radius * Math.sin(latRads) * Math.sin(lngRads);

      return {x: x, y: y, z: z};
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't post comment so i'll start an "answer" although its not one:

In the getXYZ the radius can be passed as a parameter, but in the inverse function radius cannot be a parameter: it must be length(vector). Try replace the "radius = radius || 200;" by var radius = length(vector)" and remove the radius argument (didnt test).