# Convert a list of surveyor points in Longitude and Latitude near equatorial to Cartesian system

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, geometry

I have a list of surveyor points in longitude and latitude, obtained from Google Maps, and now I want to convert them to X and Y coordinate system ( in meter). My surveyor points cover around 10 km^2, at most. My surveyor points located near or at the equatorial.

I understand that there are a few ways to [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1185408/3834). But I want a quick way. can I then use [spherical approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1185413/3834), given that my points are located near or at the equatorial?

Comment: I am asking whether can I use  spherical approximation, given that my points are located near or at the equatorial? And why is it closed "too broad"? This is terrible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for quick and dirty "projection" of small region near equator you can use simple approximation.

If your region has border values `Lat0, Lon0, Lat1, Lon1` and you want to get meters:

```
LatDiff = Lat1 - Lat0
Londiff = Lon1 - Lon0

Scale = 10 000 000 meters / 90 degrees = 111 111 m/degree
// 1/4 part of meridian length

y = (latitude - Lat0) * Scale
x = (longitude - Lon0) * Cos(average_latitude) * Scale
```

Cosine of latitude (same value for the whole region) compensates error near 1.5% for lat 10 degrees, 6% for lat 20 degrees, and might be omitted if needed.

Comment: What is `scale`?

Comment: Coefficient to make a map of defined size. For example, if coordinate difference is about angular minute, and picture should be about 1000 pixels width, `scale = 1000px / (1/60)`

Comment: I wrote more detailed example

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. The `Width` and `Height` refer to?

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to draw/show a map with points. Map is picture, it has desired size - width and height, hasn't it?

Comment: Ah, I want to convert the lat/long. into Cartesian coordinate ( in meter). Question updated, sorry for the unclear question.

Comment: No problem. You just have to change a scale. Look at edit