# inverse distance weighting interpolation for GPS locations

Tags: java, python

I have a set of coordiantes(long,lat) as stations and one center coordinate which I should compute the weight of each station to this center coordinate using IDW.

My problem is that all of the implementation for [IDW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting) are for cartesian coordinate(x,y) on a flat map and not langitute and latitude for the earth. I use [Haversine_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to get the distance between locations and after that I don't know how to apply it to IDW formula.

I would appretiate any help and code in advanced.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you need to convert Cartesian coordinates to longitude & latitude.
The conversion formula is:
lat = asin(z / R)
lon = atan2(y, x)
For more details, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates

Comment: @Shahar-Rotshtein , Not really, IDW formula computes the weight based on the distances between two point and now here I compute the distance differently because of the earth's surface