# How to convert latitude and longitude to X and Y with center of coordinates in some point using standard WGS84?

Tags: python, math, coordinates, converters, wgs84

For example, I have a list of coordinates (lat, lon):

```
Coords_of_points = [(57.769999999999996, 108.06), 
                    (60.271336095306005, 119.70058684113518), 
                    (55.44781555321857, 121.56598882454766), 
                    (42.39597453807919, 141.90642068006264), 
                    (47.416832694979675, 126.65598006176236)]
Center_of_coordinates = (48.528055555555554, 135.18805555555556)
```

For calculating X and Y of points from `Center_of_coordinates`, I use this function:

```
def transform(Coords_of_points, Center_of_coordinates):
    for i in range(len(Coords_of_points)):
        line = Coords_of_points[i]
        rad = 6372795
        lat_point = math.radians(line[0])
        lon_point = math.radians(line[1])
        lat_0 = math.radians(Center_of_coordinates[0])
        lon_0 = math.radians(Center_of_coordinates[1])
        cl1 = math.cos(lat_0)
        cl2 = math.cos(lat_point)
        sl1 = math.sin(lat_0)
        sl2 = math.sin(lat_point)
        delta = lon_point - lon_0
        cdelta = math.cos(delta)
        sdelta = math.sin(delta)
        y = math.sqrt(math.pow(cl2 * sdelta, 2) + math.pow(cl1 * sl2 - sl1 * cl2 * cdelta, 2))
        x = sl1 * sl2 + cl1 * cl2 * cdelta
        ad = math.atan2(y, x)
        dist = ad * rad
        x = (cl1 * sl2) - (sl1 * cl2 * cdelta)
        y = sdelta * cl2
        z = math.degrees(math.atan(-y / x))
        if (x < 0):
            z = z + 180
        z2 = (z + 180.) % 360. - 180
        z2 = - math.radians(z2)
        anglerad2 = z2 - ((2 * math.pi) * math.floor((z2 / (2 * math.pi))))
        x = round(((math.sin(anglerad2) * dist) / 1000), 3)
        y = round(((math.cos(anglerad2) * dist) / 1000), 3)
        yield x,y
```

This function works good when points located near with `Center_of_coordinates`, but if they located to far from `Center_of_coordinates`, X and Y has been calculating with mistake, I guess this is happening due to Earth Curvature.

So, if i have Point `(57.769999999999996, 108.06)`, its X and Y from `Center_of_coordinates` will be calculated as `(-1577, 1326.651)`. The coorrect answer should be: `(-1590, 1338.34)`.

Anybody know how to modify or maybe change the whole algoritm to get correct X and Y of points using WGS84?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting from longitude\latitude to Cartesian coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates)

Comment: Quite a few answers searching with `lat lon conversion to cartesian wgs84 site:stackoverflow.com` - also some over at [gis.stackexchange](https://www.bing.com/search?q=python+gis+cartesian+lat+lon+wgs84+site%3agis.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You need to be using spherical calcs - You can compare with this tool - https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/NCAT/ -