# GAMS csv read issue

Tags: csv, input, gams-math

I'm trying to read a .csv file with the following format using MAC:

```
;lon;lat
0;55,245594;25,066697
1;55,135613;25,070419
2;55,275683;25,203425
```

What I am doing so far is:

```
$call csv2gdx coords.csv id=d index=1 values=2..lastCol useHeader=y

sets
  i 
  c /x,y/
;

parameters
  dloc(i,c) 'locations'
;

$gdxin clients_csv.gdx
$load ___ ?
```

What I want to do is read the lat,lon coordinates in the parameter dloc so as for each i to have a pair of coords c, i.e. lat, lon.

Example output:

```
           x           y

i1      17.175      84.327
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your code produces an error from csv2gdx:

```
*** ErrNr = 15 Msg = Values(s) column number exceeds column count; Index = 2, ColCnt = 1
```

Per default, csv2gdx expects the entries separated by commas, which you do not have in your data. You could also define `semicolon` or `tab` as separator by means of an option, but if the data has really the format you posted, you do not need to call `csv2gdx` at all. You could just include the data directly like this:

```
Sets
  i 
  c
;

Table dloc(i<,c<) 'locations'
$include coords.csv
;

Display dloc;
```

---

EDIT after change of input data format:

The error message is still the same. And also the reason is the same: You use a different field separator than the default one. If you switch that using the option `fieldSep=semiColon`, you will realize that also your decimal separator is non-default for csv2gdx. But this can be changed as well. Here is the whole code (with adjusted csv2gdx call and adjustments for data loading). Note that sets `i` and `c` get implicitly defined when loading `dloc` with the `<` syntax in the declaration of `dloc`.

```
$call csv2gdx coords.csv id=d index=1 values=2..lastCol useHeader=y fieldSep=semiColon  decimalSep=comma

Sets
  i 
  c
;

parameters
  dloc(i<,c<) 'locations'
;

$gdxin coords.gdx
$load dloc=d

Display dloc;
$exit\
```

Comment: pleas see the edit. The data are comma separated values.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you maybe have an idea on how I can convert all those lat lon coordinates to x,y after I load them in a single pass?

Comment: Not sure, if I got that right: You just want that the labels are called x/y instead of lat/lon?

Comment: after loading with the above mentioned piece of code my coordinates, I want to convert them to x,y cartesian coordinates instead of lat, lon being loaded.

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates