# Nearest distance of a point to line expressed in geo coordinates format

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry, geocoding

I am working on a javascript application where I need to find the nearest line from a point. Every point is expressed in geo format (latitude and longitude). So I want to calculate the minimum distance of point to every line and compare that to find the nearest line.

The problem is how do I find the nearest distance to a line of a point in geo format? There are some methods given for x-y coordinate system but I don't know how to use them in geo coding format.

Can someone give me some pointers as how to do it? Though I am looking for javascript solution but even language-agnostic approach is fine.

Comment: It sounds like you want to compute distances between entities that exist in different worlds: how do you represent the lines using geo coordinates? I'm not aware of a method for doing this. Maybe convert your points to cartesian coordinates, and then worry about finding the closest line.

Comment: @IVlad Actually the line is represented as its start and end point expressed in latitude-longitude format. I am sorry but I don't understand why is this invalid format to represent line on map?

Comment: Ok, maybe that is easier then. I thought you meant a straight line, sorry.

Comment: No I didn't mean that, sorry for the confusion. Can you please provide the answer?

Comment: I'll think about it, but I don't have one at the moment. My initial thought was to convert geo -> cartesian and go from there, but that's off the table now.

Comment: Surprising, it appears this has already been asked before: [How to calculate distance from a point to a line segment, on a sphere?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299567/how-to-calculate-distance-from-a-point-to-a-line-segment-on-a-sphere) Please let me know if this is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does seem exactly like what I want. I will give it a try and let you know if it works.

Comment: @Naman, have you got any answer for this question?  I am having same problem and not able to find the solution. Can you please post your solution here? Thanks.