# Getting point on line segment that is closest to another point

Tags: c++, math, sfml

I want to find a point on segment line AB, that is closest to another point P.

My idea was:

1. Get `a1` and `b1` from line formula `y1 = a1x + b1`, using A and B points coordinates.
2. Get normal line formula, from `a1` and P coordinates, `y2 = a2x + b2`.
3. Get intersection point x coord, by equating `y1` and `y2` and next using one of above formulas, to get y.

[image]

My code:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

sf::Vector2f getClosestPointOnLine(sf::Vector2f A, sf::Vector2f B, sf::Vector2f P)
{
    //convert to line formula
    float a = (B.y - A.y)/(B.x - A.x);
    float b = -a * A.x + A.y;

    //get normal line formula
    float a2 = -a / 2;
    float b2 = -a2 * P.x + P.y;

    //get x
    float a3 = a - a2;
    float b3 = b2 - b;

    float x = b3 / a3;

    //get y
    float y = a * x + b;

    return { x, y };
}

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow gameWindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "App");

    sf::View view(sf::FloatRect(0, 0, 800, 600));
    gameWindow.setView(view);

    gameWindow.setFramerateLimit(60);

    sf::VertexArray plane(sf::LinesStrip, 2);

    plane[0] = { { view.getSize().x * 0.5f, view.getSize().y * 0.8f } };
    plane[1] = { { view.getSize().x * 0.8f, view.getSize().y * 0.6f } };

    sf::CircleShape ball(10);

    ball.setOrigin(10, 10);
    ball.setPosition({view.getSize().x * 0.7f, view.getSize().y * 0.4f});

    while (gameWindow.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event e;
        while (gameWindow.pollEvent(e))
        {
            if (e.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                gameWindow.close();
            }
        }

        //draw
        gameWindow.clear(sf::Color{30, 30, 30});

        ball.setPosition((sf::Vector2f)sf::Mouse::getPosition(gameWindow));

        sf::Vector2f closest = getClosestPointOnLine(plane[0].position, plane[1].position, ball.getPosition());

        sf::CircleShape cs(5);
        cs.setOrigin(5, 5 );
        cs.setPosition(closest);

        gameWindow.draw(cs);
        gameWindow.draw(plane);
        gameWindow.draw(ball);
        gameWindow.display();
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

As you can see function `getClosestPointOnLine` returns me wrong intersection point.
What is wrong with my function?

------------------EDIT: 
As n.m. mentioned, `-a / 2` is not formula for normal line slope, I was wrong with this formula, the right is: `-1 / a`.

Comment: To blend away all the implementation details, what is given and what do you want to have ? (Good pictures btw)

Comment: `float a2 = -a / 2;` is not a normal line formula, where did you get that? Your idea also doesn't take into account that lines can be vertical and horizontal.

Comment: @user1767754 I have weird offset, the line between bigger point and smaller point in the line segment must be normal to that line segment.

Answer (score 16):

What you want is the projection of `P` onto the line segment. You can do this with the dot product:

```
auto AB = B - A;
auto AP = P - A;
float lengthSqrAB = AB.x * AB.x + AB.y * AB.y;
float t = (AP.x * AB.x + AP.y * AB.y) / lengthSqrAB;
```

Now, `t` is the interpolation parameter between `A` and `B`. If it is `0`, then the point projects onto `A`. If it is `1`, it projects onto `B`. Fractional values represent points in between. If you want to restrict the projection to the line segment, then you need to clamp `t`:

```
if(t < 0)
    t = 0;
if(t > 1)
    t = 1;
```

And finally, you can calculate the point:

```
return A + t * AB;
```

Comment: Could you explain exactly how and why the t calculation works?

Comment: @BossCode: If you are interested in the math behind it, check out the [Wikipedia article about vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection). The figures there visualize the concept much better than I could in a comment.