# Calculate radius from coordinates and find all matches within the radius in a table

Tags: php, mysql, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL: Determine if one coordinate is in radius of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896213/sql-determine-if-one-coordinate-is-in-radius-of-another)

In a table I have stored latitude and longitude (as floats). Now I want to query my table to find all rows which have coordinates within a given radius (which can ben 2km, 5km, 10km etc. etc.). I really don't have a clue how to achieve this so any help will be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure how query, because I think the result will be an endless set of coordinates representing the 'border' of the radius where I somehow have to tell my table to search for results within that 'border'.

Comment: you'll need the 'GREAT CIRCLE DISTANCE' formula

Comment: I'm going to Google that now. thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896213/sql-determine-if-one-coordinate-is-in-radius-of-another

could help you, maybe

Answer (score 4):

You need to familiarize yourself with the [Haversine forumla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula) This will calculate the distances from lat and lon as you expected through mysql

Comment: Thanks for your answer, +1. I'm going to try Shubhansh solution first, if that won't work I'll give your suggestion a try.