# Geolocation: Get latitude and longitude with distance

Tags: php, geolocation, distance, latitude-longitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL: Determine if one coordinate is in radius of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896213/sql-determine-if-one-coordinate-is-in-radius-of-another)

I've got a question about geolocation in PHP.

I've got latitude and longitude values. Do you know how can I have new values from distance?

I mean, I want to have all the stores 1 or 2 miles around, for example, from a position.
My database contains shops with latitude and longitude values, and I want to have all near stores.

Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Are you storing the places in a database or are you using an API for them? How many places will there in be (more or less)?

Comment: If you have everything locally, you can just do the math yourself: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/3945/5085

Comment: deceze : Oh yes, it's a good code ! But... how can i get it in meters ? thanks a lot. eskimo : i'm storing the place in the database yes, maybe 10 000 places in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *probably* use a Google Maps API - eg. [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) for this. Look into their documentation, its rich with good info.