# How to retrieve data from a table, based on user coordinates and the radius

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, latitude-longitude

Basically I send a GET request to a `php` file with the user lat and long values (`$userLat, $userLong` respectively).

In my database, I have a table 'Locations' that has the following columns:

- Location_Name
- Lat
- Lng
- Radius (in meters)

So, I wanna make a query where I compare the user's coordinates with all the Locations coordinates and see if the distance between the Location and the User is <= the radius of that location. If so, return the name of that Location.

The query would be something like this (pseudo-code):

> SELECT Location_Name FROM Locations WHERE distanceBetween(($userLat, $userLong) AND (Lat, Lng)) <= Radius

Comment: a very good description at http://de.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896213/determine-if-one-coordinate-is-in-radius-of-another

Comment: Here is an updated version that uses SPATIAL functions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739309/mysql-point-spatial-index-query-within-radius-from-center-point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the same query as @socca1157 answered with but thought I could offer a tiny explanation of the constant `3959` at the start of the query.

My example also gets the lat and lng of a user's address

```
$address = urlencode($_GET['user-address']);

$earth_radius = 3959;
$search_radius = 100;

$ch = curl_init('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.'&sensor=false');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$geocode = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$output = json_decode($geocode);

$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$lng = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;


$sql = "SELECT *, ( $earth_radius * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM table WHERE isActive = 1 HAVING distance < $search_radius ORDER BY distance LIMIT 5";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

so, for example, if you wanted to search in km instead of miles, you'd use the radius of the earth in km, which is 6,371km.

Comment: thank you so much! it's works perfectly as far as i've tested it. thank you

Answer (score 2):

The query you're looking for is:

`SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;`

This was taken from a [Google Map's article](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3).