# MySQL POINT spatial index query within radius from center POINT

Tags: mysql

I see many solutions for getting the nearest rows from a `POINT` to convert to `X()` and `Y()` and do trig calculations of distances... As I understand, this does not seem to take advantage of the spatial index?

How do you take advantage of the spatial index, in the most common sense of, returning rows whose spatial `POINT` is within a radius from a center `POINT`?

In other words, how do you get something like this - where `LatLng` is the lat lng location stored as POINT for each row, and `CenterPoint` the epicenter

Pseudocode query: `SELECT * FROM geotable WHERE d=Distance(LatLng,CenterPoint) < 10 ORDER by d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use st_distance_sphere

```
SELECT * 
FROM geotable 
WHERE st_distance_sphere(POINT(-82.337036, 29.645095 ), POINT(`longitude`, `latitude` ))/1000  < 10
```

Here you can see a [working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ecf86b9e822631868dd0792df83766d7)

Comment: Interesting! So the column itself is not `POINT` but two separate `latitude`, `longitude` columns?

Comment: also why did you use varchar instead of decimal for lat/long?

Comment: that was the problem, that the data was in that form, but you can use Point, if you saved it that way.

Comment: also how do you order by distance?

Comment: simply like any other calculated column or order by st_distance_sphere(...) ASC

Comment: should you assign that as an alias first though? (if so, how?) otherwise - does it do that calculation twice?

Comment: ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(POINT(- 82.337036, 29.645095), POINT(`longitude`, `latitude`)) / 1000 AS distance

Comment: where do you put that though?

Comment: could you please take a look at the provided example link

Comment: This answer makes no use of the spatial index. You should instead query points related to your indexed points with one of [these spatial relation functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-mbr.html) like in [this example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-spatial-indexes.html).

Comment: As always you are free to post your own answer, this method os approved under may circumstances and it quick and simple to understand