# help with GPS position

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

if i have this position: `32.226743,34.747009`

and i need to know that i in the range of  10 meter from this position

how to know this ?

(i work on C# Windows-mobile 2005)

thank's in advance

Comment: Are you trying to answer the question 'Given this position fix from a GPS what is the likelihood that I am no more than 10m away from that position ?' or the question 'Is the distance between position A and position B less than 10m ?'

Comment: i explain, i standing in any position, i need to know if i'am in radius of 10 m from 32.226743,34.747009 position

Comment: why was this down voted? it seems to be a perfectly straight forward question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [calculate distance between 2 gps coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get the current position you could [calculate the distance between those two points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) and test if it is less than 10 meters.

Answer (score 1):

I will take the question literally, without trying to guess what you really meant:

1. you have to get  a second position (where you are)
2. calculate the distance between the 2 locations
3. check if it is less than 10 meters

Answer (score 1):

here is a link that might help

[Latitude, Longitude, Bearing, Cardinal Direction, Distance, and C#](http://bryan.reynoldslive.com/post/Latitude2c-Longitude2c-Bearing2c-Cardinal-Direction2c-Distance2c-and-C.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Then use the [great-circle distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance).  THough in reality, when looking at such short distances with respect to the planet's radius, a simple 2D [euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between two points is going to be close enough.

Answer (score 0):

most laguage support fancutions to calculate it .. and i used it before in java and c#
This code in c#:

```
GeoCoordinate sCoord = new GeoCoordinate(88, 88);
        var eCoord = new GeoCoordinate(90, 90);

        return sCoord.GetDistanceTo(eCoord);
```