# GPS delta coordinates to meters

Tags: gps, coordinates, distance, delta, meter

Greetings,

I have two coordinates:

```
(52.4412396, -6.563223)
```

and

```
(52.8912397, -6.683669)
```

The delta is:

```
(-0.4499999, 0.120446)
```

The distance moved is:

```
sqrt((-0.4499999)^2+(0.120446)^2)
=.465840261
```

How do I convert this to meters?!

I hope someone can help.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [calculate distance between 2 gps coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates)

Answer (score 3):

You have mistakenly done the sum of squares on spherical coordinates. Each difference has to be converted to its longitudinal and latitudinal distance before getting the hypotenuse. While latitude converts directly to distance, (each degree is equal to 60 nautical miles) the longitude will only do that at the equator) That means that you have to multiply the above by the cosine of the latitude. Then you can move on to a simple hypotenuse calculation before converting to meters.