# geolocation with javascript and ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**view.html.erb**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
 location();
</script>
```

**toggle.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(function location()
{
  alert("here in loc1233");

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
  } 
  else {
   alert("here in loc");
  }
 });    //showmap

 $(function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lot = position.coords.longitude;
   alert('Your location coordinates are: Latitude:'+lat+' Longitude: '+lot);
 });
 });
```

Here when call the function location() in toggle.js, but its only give the alert

alert("here in loc1233");

its doesn't go to that rest of the line in that function. Why giving like that?

thanks

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908370/html5-geolocation-implementation

Answer (score 0):

Why you writing functions in jQuery object?? and where is the errorFunction written??

> ```
>           $(document).ready(function() {
>             $(function location()
>             {
>               alert("here in loc1233");
>               if (navigator.geolocation){navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
>               } 
>               else {
>                alert("here in loc");
>               }
>              });    //showmap
>              function successFunction(position) {
>                 var lat = position.coords.latitude;
>                 var lot = position.coords.longitude;
>                alert('Your location coordinates are: Latitude:'+lat+' Longitude: '+lot);
>              }
>              function errorFunction(position){
>                 alert('alert')
>              }
>              });
> ```