# How to calculate the current speed and average speed of user travelling from current location to particular locaction in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performance, mapkit, distance

I am having a map application. When a person travels from current location to particular location I want to calculate the distance covered by the person, the current speed of the person, average speed of the person.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use following methods to get distance in miles or kilometers. You have to declare timer in your header file synthesize it.

```
//SpeedViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>

@interface SpeedViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locManager;
    CLLocationSpeed speed;
    NSTimer *timer;

    CLLocationSpeed currentSpeed;
    float fltDistanceTravelled; 
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSTimer *timer;

-(float)getDistanceInKm:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;
-(float)getDistanceInMiles:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;

@end

//SpeedViewController.h
#import "SpeedViewController.h"
#define kRequiredAccuracy 500.0 //meters
#define kMaxAge 10.0 //seconds
#define M_PI   3.14159265358979323846264338327950288   /* pi */


@implementation SpeedViewController

@synthesize timer;
- (void)startReadingLocation {
    [locManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CLLocationManager *locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    NSLog(@"new->%d old->%d",(newLocation==NULL),(oldLocation==NULL));

    if(newLocation && oldLocation)
    {
        fltDistanceTravelled +=[self getDistanceInKm:newLocation fromLocation:oldLocation];
    }
}

//this is a wrapper method to fit the required selector signature
- (void)timeIntervalEnded:(NSTimer*)timer {
    fltDistanceTravelled=0;
    [self startReadingLocation];
}


-(float)getDistanceInKm:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    float lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2;

    lat1 = newLocation.coordinate.latitude  * M_PI / 180;
    lon1 = newLocation.coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180;

    lat2 = oldLocation.coordinate.latitude  * M_PI / 180;   
    lon2 = oldLocation.coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180;

    float R = 6371; // km
    float dLat = lat2-lat1;
    float dLon = lon2-lon1; 

    float a = sin(dLat/2) * sin(dLat/2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dLon/2) * sin(dLon/2); 
    float c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a)); 
    float d = R * c;

    NSLog(@"Kms-->%f",d);

    return d;
}

-(float)getDistanceInMiles:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    float lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2;

    lat1 = newLocation.coordinate.latitude  * M_PI / 180;
    lon1 = newLocation.coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180;

    lat2 = oldLocation.coordinate.latitude  * M_PI / 180;   
    lon2 = oldLocation.coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180;

    float R = 3963; // km
    float dLat = lat2-lat1;
    float dLon = lon2-lon1; 

    float a = sin(dLat/2) * sin(dLat/2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dLon/2) * sin(dLon/2); 
    float c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a)); 
    float d = R * c;

    NSLog(@"Miles-->%f",d);

    return d;
}

@end
```

I have not tested this on device but logically it should work.

Comment: i know the method startUpdatingLocation .is startReadingLocation and startUpdatingLocation same

Comment: i have searched startReadingLocation method in developer documentation but it contains only stopupdatinglocation and  startupdatinglocation. the readinglocation method is a standard method or user defined

Comment: @Rani I Apologize, just forgot to put that method in that code. Updated the code.

Comment: Hi jennis, i have tried but it is giving me an error that        invalid operands to binary + (have 'float' and 'id') on the line fltDistanceTravelled +=[self getDistanceInKm:newLocation fromLocation:oldLocation]; i have declared fltDistanceTravelled as a float variable.Thanks

Comment: @Rani I have updated the answer and pasted full implementation. Check out and leave comment if any further help required.

Comment: thanks jennis it is working, i have tried in simulator it is working.i have not tried on a device

Answer (score 2):

In order to determine any speed, you'll want to figure:

**Distance**: Take your two latest geographic coordinate readings (and the time each was recorded) to calculate the distance between them

To do this, you can read about theory [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), or you can check out code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates).

**Speed**: Using the distance between the latest GPS coordinate reading and the previous, calculate the speed by the formula speed = distance/duration. So, the distance you found between the two geo coordinates divided by the duration in seconds or minutes or whatever. Then your answer will be speed is x miles or kilometers per whatever.