# Calculating heading between two latitude and longitude in iPhone

Tags: iphone, latitude-longitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [how to calculate the current speed and average speed of user travelling from current location to particular loaction in map in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988590/how-to-calculate-the-current-speed-and-average-speed-of-user-travelling-from-curr)

I have a situation where i should not use CLLocationManger class.I am given with two latitude and longitude values(a source and destination).I want find out the heading from these two points in iPhone.How can i do this?

I referred to the formula in this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171219235009/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55417.html).But i am not able to get the heading.Please any body help me in calculating the heading

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Why is this question considered duplicate? The linked duplicate question does not calculate heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are. These are 2 functions you can use to calculate distance between 2 Locations.

```
-(float)getDistanceInKm:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    float lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2;

    lat1 = newLocation.coordinate.latitude  * M_PI / 180;
    lon1 = newLocation.coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180;

    lat2 = oldLocation.coordinate.latitude  * M_PI / 180;   
    lon2 = oldLocation.coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180;

    float R = 6371; // km
    float dLat = lat2-lat1;
    float dLon = lon2-lon1; 

    float a = sin(dLat/2) * sin(dLat/2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dLon/2) * sin(dLon/2); 
    float c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a)); 
    float d = R * c;

    NSLog(@"Kms-->%f",d);

    return d;
}

-(float)getDistanceInMiles:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    float lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2;

    lat1 = newLocation.coordinate.latitude  * M_PI / 180;
    lon1 = newLocation.coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180;

    lat2 = oldLocation.coordinate.latitude  * M_PI / 180;   
    lon2 = oldLocation.coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180;

    float R = 3963; // km
    float dLat = lat2-lat1;
    float dLon = lon2-lon1; 

    float a = sin(dLat/2) * sin(dLat/2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dLon/2) * sin(dLon/2); 
    float c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a)); 
    float d = R * c;

    NSLog(@"Miles-->%f",d);

    return d;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Jennis,thanks for your reply.But here you have used CLLocation Manager class.But my situation is i just have only two set of latitude and longitude which comes from the webservice.I want to findout the distance,heading and bearing...Please let me know your thoughts..

Comment: @Sankar you can create CLLocation object with the help of following statement. CLLocation *yourLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:yourLatitude longitude:yourLongitude];

Comment: Thanks Jennis...I hope this will work..I try to implement this and let you know the feedback..Thanks a lot Jennis for your response

Comment: @Sankar If it works according to your requirement please mark this as accepted solution or upvote for answer.

Comment: Ya sure man i will definitely do that...

Comment: hey i think what you need is a function to get the heading from two locations. Given an object that has lat,lng attirbutes you could do this:    -(float)getHeadingForDirectionToCoordinate:(double)fromLat fromLng:(double)fromLng
{
    float tLat = radians([self.lat floatValue]);
    float tLng = radians([self.lng floatValue]);
    float fLat = radians(fromLat);
    float fLng = radians(fromLng);
    float brng =  atan2(sin(tLng-fLng)*cos(tLat), cos(fLat)*sin(tLat)-sin(fLat)*cos(tLat)*cos(tLng-fLng)); 
    return = fmodf((degrees(brng) + 360), 360);
}    if someone could reopen the question...