# calculate the speed in kilometer/hour using core location framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I am calculating the distance and speed as below.

```
totalDistance=totalDistance+[newLocation distanceFromLocation:self
->tempOldLocation];
distanceLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f km", (totalDistance
/1000)];
self->tempOldLocation=newLocation;
```

Calculating Speed:

```
CLLocationDistance distanceChange = [newLocation getDistanceFrom:oldLocation];
NSTimeInterval sinceLastUpdate = [newLocation.timestamp 
       timeIntervalSinceDate:oldLocation.timestamp];
double calculatedSpeed = distanceChange / sinceLastUpdate;
```

I want to calculate the speed in km/h. Please suggest me any way to calculate the speed in km/h.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988590/how-to-calculate-the-current-speed-and-average-speed-of-user-travelling-from-cur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are dividing meters to seconds, giving you meters per second.
Convert meters to KMS, and seconds to hours

```
double calculatedSpeed = (distanceChange / 1000) / (sinceLastUpdate / 60 / 60)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get speed directly from the `CLLocationSpeed` property of `CLLocation` obtained at delegate method `didUpdateLocation`.

Answer (score 0):

In CLLocationManagerDelegate use method didUpdateLocations:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let speed = locations.last?.speed else { return }

    viewModel.speed.value = speed * 3600/1000
}
```