# Function to calculate distance between two coordinates

Tags: javascript, coordinates, distance

I'm currently using the function below and it doesn't work properly. According to Google Maps, the distance between [these coordinates](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!4m14!3m13!1m1!1s59.3293371%2C13.4877472!1m1!1s59.3225525%2C13.4619422!3m8!1m3!1d31685072!2d-95.677068!3d37.0625!3m2!1i1280!2i933!4f13.1&fid=0) (from `59.3293371,13.4877472` to `59.3225525,13.4619422`) are `2.2` kilometres while the function returns `1.6` kilometres. How can I make this function return the correct distance?

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/gAHJB/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points)

Answer (score 310, accepted):

What you're using is called the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), which calculates the distance between two points on a sphere *as the crow flies*.  The Google Maps link you provided shows the distance as 2.2 km because it's not a straight line.

Wolfram Alpha is a great resource for doing geographic calculations, and also shows a distance of [1.652 km between these two points](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=59.3293371N+13.4877472W+to+59.3225525N+13.4619422W+in+km).

[image: Drive distance vs. straight line distance (red line mine).]

If you're looking for straight-line distance (as the crow files), your function is working correctly.  If what you want is driving distance (or biking distance or public transportation distance or walking distance), you'll have to use a mapping API ([Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) or [Bing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701705.aspx) being the most popular) to get the appropriate route, which will include the distance.

Incidentally, the Google Maps API provides a packaged method for spherical distance, in its [`google.maps.geometry.spherical` namespace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) (look for `computeDistanceBetween`).  It's probably better than rolling your own (for starters, it uses a more precise value for the Earth's radius).

For the picky among us, when I say "as the crow flies" or "straight-line distance", I'm referring to a "straight line on a sphere", which is actually a curved line (i.e. the great-circle distance), of course.

Comment: My pleasure!  It was fun to answer.

Comment: It's a beautiful answer. I say beautiful because the details provided are just too good for understanding the difference even for a novice like me.

Answer (score 141):

I have written a similar equation before - tested it and also got 1.6 km.

Your google maps was showing the DRIVING distance.

Your function is calculating as the crow flies (straight line distance).

```
alert(calcCrow(59.3293371,13.4877472,59.3225525,13.4619422).toFixed(1));



    //This function takes in latitude and longitude of two location and returns the distance between them as the crow flies (in km)
    function calcCrow(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) 
    {
      var R = 6371; // km
      var dLat = toRad(lat2-lat1);
      var dLon = toRad(lon2-lon1);
      var lat1 = toRad(lat1);
      var lat2 = toRad(lat2);

      var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
      var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
      var d = R * c;
      return d;
    }

    // Converts numeric degrees to radians
    function toRad(Value) 
    {
        return Value * Math.PI / 180;
    }
```

Comment: I think your variable names are way too descriptive :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates

Comment: this returns meters, not km
d = R * c; returns meters
d = R * c / 1000.0;  returns kilometers

Answer (score 26):

Derek's solution worked fine for me, and I've just simply converted it to PHP, hope it helps somebody out there !

```
function calcCrow($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2){
        $R = 6371; // km
        $dLat = toRad($lat2-$lat1);
        $dLon = toRad($lon2-$lon1);
        $lat1 = toRad($lat1);
        $lat2 = toRad($lat2);

        $a = sin($dLat/2) * sin($dLat/2) +sin($dLon/2) * sin($dLon/2) * cos($lat1) * cos($lat2); 
        $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1-$a)); 
        $d = $R * $c;
        return $d;
}

// Converts numeric degrees to radians
function toRad($Value) 
{
    return $Value * pi() / 180;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Using Haversine formula, [source of the code](https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/javascript):

```
//:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
//:::                                                                         :::
//:::  This routine calculates the distance between two points (given the     :::
//:::  latitude/longitude of those points). It is being used to calculate     :::
//:::  the distance between two locations using GeoDataSource (TM) prodducts  :::
//:::                                                                         :::
//:::  Definitions:                                                           :::
//:::    South latitudes are negative, east longitudes are positive           :::
//:::                                                                         :::
//:::  Passed to function:                                                    :::
//:::    lat1, lon1 = Latitude and Longitude of point 1 (in decimal degrees)  :::
//:::    lat2, lon2 = Latitude and Longitude of point 2 (in decimal degrees)  :::
//:::    unit = the unit you desire for results                               :::
//:::           where: 'M' is statute miles (default)                         :::
//:::                  'K' is kilometers                                      :::
//:::                  'N' is nautical miles                                  :::
//:::                                                                         :::
//:::  Worldwide cities and other features databases with latitude longitude  :::
//:::  are available at https://www.geodatasource.com                         :::
//:::                                                                         :::
//:::  For enquiries, please contact sales@geodatasource.com                  :::
//:::                                                                         :::
//:::  Official Web site: https://www.geodatasource.com                       :::
//:::                                                                         :::
//:::               GeoDataSource.com (C) All Rights Reserved 2018            :::
//:::                                                                         :::
//:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
    if ((lat1 == lat2) && (lon1 == lon2)) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
        var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
        var theta = lon1-lon2;
        var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
        var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
        if (dist > 1) {
            dist = 1;
        }
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
        if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
        return dist;
    }
}
```

*The sample code is licensed under LGPLv3.*

Comment: why you are doing this ? if (dist > 1) {
            dist = 1;
        }

Comment: This was very useful, and much more accurate than some other answers I found

Answer (score 16):

Adding this for Node.JS users. You can use the `haversine-distance` module to do this so you won't need to handle the calculations on your own. See the [npm page for more information](https://www.npmjs.com/package/haversine-distance).

To install:

> npm install --save haversine-distance

You can use the module as follows:

```
var haversine = require("haversine-distance");

//First point in your haversine calculation
var point1 = { lat: 6.1754, lng: 106.8272 }

//Second point in your haversine calculation
var point2 = { lat: 6.1352, lng: 106.8133 }

var haversine_m = haversine(point1, point2); //Results in meters (default)
var haversine_km = haversine_m /1000; //Results in kilometers

console.log("distance (in meters): " + haversine_m + "m");
console.log("distance (in kilometers): " + haversine_km + "km");
```

Answer (score 14):

Update: i created a npm package that implements the algorithm below: https://www.npmjs.com/package/calculate-distance-between-coordinates

---

I implemeneted [this algorithm](https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/javascript) in typescript and ES6

```
export type Coordinate = {
  lat: number;
  lon: number;
};
```

get the distance between two points:

```
function getDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(cord1: Coordinate, cord2: Coordinate) {
  if (cord1.lat == cord2.lat && cord1.lon == cord2.lon) {
    return 0;
  }

  const radlat1 = (Math.PI * cord1.lat) / 180;
  const radlat2 = (Math.PI * cord2.lat) / 180;

  const theta = cord1.lon - cord2.lon;
  const radtheta = (Math.PI * theta) / 180;

  let dist =
    Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) +
    Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);

  if (dist > 1) {
    dist = 1;
  }

  dist = Math.acos(dist);
  dist = (dist * 180) / Math.PI;
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  dist = dist * 1.609344; //convert miles to km
  
  return dist;
}
```

get the distance between an array of coordinates

```
export function getTotalDistance(coordinates: Coordinate[]) {
  coordinates = coordinates.filter((cord) => {
    if (cord.lat && cord.lon) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  
  let totalDistance = 0;

  if (!coordinates) {
    return 0;
  }

  if (coordinates.length < 2) {
    return 0;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < coordinates.length - 2; i++) {
    if (
      !coordinates[i].lon ||
      !coordinates[i].lat ||
      !coordinates[i + 1].lon ||
      !coordinates[i + 1].lat
    ) {
      totalDistance = totalDistance;
    }
    totalDistance =
      totalDistance +
      getDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(coordinates[i], coordinates[i + 1]);
  }

  return totalDistance.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks for the TypeScript example!!!

Comment: I created an npm package with this code so you don't have to copy-paste it 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/calculate-distance-between-coordinates

Answer (score 10):

Calculate the Distance between Two Points in javascript

```
function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
        var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180
        var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180
        var theta = lon1-lon2
        var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180
        var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
        dist = Math.acos(dist)
        dist = dist * 180/Math.PI
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
        if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
        if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
        return dist
}
```

For more details refer this: [Reference Link](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/calculate-the-distance-between-two-points-in-your-web-apps.html)

Answer (score 5):

Try this. It is in VB.net and you need to convert it to Javascript. This function accepts parameters in decimal minutes.

```
    Private Function calculateDistance(ByVal long1 As String, ByVal lat1 As String, ByVal long2 As String, ByVal lat2 As String) As Double
    long1 = Double.Parse(long1)
    lat1 = Double.Parse(lat1)
    long2 = Double.Parse(long2)
    lat2 = Double.Parse(lat2)

    'conversion to radian
    lat1 = (lat1 * 2.0 * Math.PI) / 60.0 / 360.0
    long1 = (long1 * 2.0 * Math.PI) / 60.0 / 360.0
    lat2 = (lat2 * 2.0 * Math.PI) / 60.0 / 360.0
    long2 = (long2 * 2.0 * Math.PI) / 60.0 / 360.0

    ' use to different earth axis length
    Dim a As Double = 6378137.0        ' Earth Major Axis (WGS84)
    Dim b As Double = 6356752.3142     ' Minor Axis
    Dim f As Double = (a - b) / a        ' "Flattening"
    Dim e As Double = 2.0 * f - f * f      ' "Eccentricity"

    Dim beta As Double = (a / Math.Sqrt(1.0 - e * Math.Sin(lat1) * Math.Sin(lat1)))
    Dim cos As Double = Math.Cos(lat1)
    Dim x As Double = beta * cos * Math.Cos(long1)
    Dim y As Double = beta * cos * Math.Sin(long1)
    Dim z As Double = beta * (1 - e) * Math.Sin(lat1)

    beta = (a / Math.Sqrt(1.0 - e * Math.Sin(lat2) * Math.Sin(lat2)))
    cos = Math.Cos(lat2)
    x -= (beta * cos * Math.Cos(long2))
    y -= (beta * cos * Math.Sin(long2))
    z -= (beta * (1 - e) * Math.Sin(lat2))

    Return Math.Sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z))
End Function
```

**Edit**
The converted function in javascript

```
function calculateDistance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2)
  {    

      //radians
      lat1 = (lat1 * 2.0 * Math.PI) / 60.0 / 360.0;      
      long1 = (long1 * 2.0 * Math.PI) / 60.0 / 360.0;    
      lat2 = (lat2 * 2.0 * Math.PI) / 60.0 / 360.0;   
      long2 = (long2 * 2.0 * Math.PI) / 60.0 / 360.0;       


      // use to different earth axis length    
      var a = 6378137.0;        // Earth Major Axis (WGS84)    
      var b = 6356752.3142;     // Minor Axis    
      var f = (a-b) / a;        // "Flattening"    
      var e = 2.0*f - f*f;      // "Eccentricity"      

      var beta = (a / Math.sqrt( 1.0 - e * Math.sin( lat1 ) * Math.sin( lat1 )));    
      var cos = Math.cos( lat1 );    
      var x = beta * cos * Math.cos( long1 );    
      var y = beta * cos * Math.sin( long1 );    
      var z = beta * ( 1 - e ) * Math.sin( lat1 );      

      beta = ( a / Math.sqrt( 1.0 -  e * Math.sin( lat2 ) * Math.sin( lat2 )));    
      cos = Math.cos( lat2 );   
      x -= (beta * cos * Math.cos( long2 ));    
      y -= (beta * cos * Math.sin( long2 ));    
      z -= (beta * (1 - e) * Math.sin( lat2 ));       

      return (Math.sqrt( (x*x) + (y*y) + (z*z) )/1000);  
    }
```

Comment: 这个问题问了JavaScript的答案。. You have to convert it to english :)

Comment: added a javascript version

Comment: Try using more meaningful names for your variables. Don't be afraid to be verbose, since nowadays javascript is usually minified and the variable names then become only useful for humans. for example:

`const earthsMajorAccess = 6378137.0;`

eliminating the need for helpful comments (since the variable name implies what it is)

Comment: This function was written more than 5 years ago. You are welcome to modify :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use a module too:

Install:

```sh
$ npm install geolib
```

Usage:

```js
import { getDistance } from 'geolib'

const distance = getDistance(
    { latitude: 51.5103, longitude: 7.49347 },
    { latitude: "51° 31' N", longitude: "7° 28' E" }
)

console.log(distance)
```

Documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib

Comment: It gives me NaN distance

Answer (score 4):

I have written the function to find distance between two coordinates. It will return distance in meter.

```
 function findDistance() {
   var R = 6371e3; // R is earth’s radius
   var lat1 = 23.18489670753479; // starting point lat
   var lat2 = 32.726601;         // ending point lat
   var lon1 = 72.62524545192719; // starting point lon
   var lon2 = 74.857025;         // ending point lon
   var lat1radians = toRadians(lat1);
   var lat2radians = toRadians(lat2);

   var latRadians = toRadians(lat2-lat1);
   var lonRadians = toRadians(lon2-lon1);

   var a = Math.sin(latRadians/2) * Math.sin(latRadians/2) +
        Math.cos(lat1radians) * Math.cos(lat2radians) *
        Math.sin(lonRadians/2) * Math.sin(lonRadians/2);
   var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

   var d = R * c;

   console.log(d)
}

function toRadians(val){
    var PI = 3.1415926535;
    return val / 180.0 * PI;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Visit this address. 
https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
You can use this code:

```
JavaScript:     

const R = 6371e3; // metres
const φ1 = lat1 * Math.PI/180; // φ, λ in radians
const φ2 = lat2 * Math.PI/180;
const Δφ = (lat2-lat1) * Math.PI/180;
const Δλ = (lon2-lon1) * Math.PI/180;

const a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
          Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
          Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

const d = R * c; // in metres
```

Comment: Not sure if the math is right (hope it is), but not depending on external libraries and using urf8 variables makes this my favorite answer....

Answer (score 2):

### **Great-circle distance - From chord length**

Here's an elegant solution applying the strategy design pattern; I hope it's readable enough.

***TwoPointsDistanceCalculatorStrategy.js*:**

```
module.exports = () =>

class TwoPointsDistanceCalculatorStrategy {

    constructor() {}

    calculateDistance({ point1Coordinates, point2Coordinates }) {}
};
```

***GreatCircleTwoPointsDistanceCalculatorStrategy.js:***

```
module.exports = ({ TwoPointsDistanceCalculatorStrategy }) =>

class GreatCircleTwoPointsDistanceCalculatorStrategy extends TwoPointsDistanceCalculatorStrategy {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Following the algorithm documented here: 
     * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Computational_formulas
     * 
     * @param {object} inputs
     * @param {array} inputs.point1Coordinates
     * @param {array} inputs.point2Coordinates
     * 
     * @returns {decimal} distance in kelometers
     */
    calculateDistance({ point1Coordinates, point2Coordinates }) {

        const convertDegreesToRadians = require('../convert-degrees-to-radians');
        const EARTH_RADIUS = 6371;   // in kelometers

        const [lat1 = 0, lon1 = 0] = point1Coordinates;
        const [lat2 = 0, lon2 = 0] = point2Coordinates;

        const radianLat1 = convertDegreesToRadians({ degrees: lat1 });
        const radianLon1 = convertDegreesToRadians({ degrees: lon1 });
        const radianLat2 = convertDegreesToRadians({ degrees: lat2 });
        const radianLon2 = convertDegreesToRadians({ degrees: lon2 });

        const centralAngle = _computeCentralAngle({ 
            lat1: radianLat1, lon1: radianLon1, 
            lat2: radianLat2, lon2: radianLon2, 
        });

        const distance = EARTH_RADIUS * centralAngle;

        return distance;
    }
};


/**
 * 
 * @param {object} inputs
 * @param {decimal} inputs.lat1
 * @param {decimal} inputs.lon1
 * @param {decimal} inputs.lat2
 * @param {decimal} inputs.lon2
 * 
 * @returns {decimal} centralAngle
 */
function _computeCentralAngle({ lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 }) {

    const chordLength = _computeChordLength({ lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 });
    const centralAngle = 2 * Math.asin(chordLength / 2);

    return centralAngle;
}


/**
 * 
 * @param {object} inputs
 * @param {decimal} inputs.lat1
 * @param {decimal} inputs.lon1
 * @param {decimal} inputs.lat2
 * @param {decimal} inputs.lon2
 * 
 * @returns {decimal} chordLength
 */
function _computeChordLength({ lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 }) {

    const { sin, cos, pow, sqrt } = Math;

    const ΔX = cos(lat2) * cos(lon2) - cos(lat1) * cos(lon1);
    const ΔY = cos(lat2) * sin(lon2) - cos(lat1) * sin(lon1);
    const ΔZ = sin(lat2) - sin(lat1);

    const ΔXSquare = pow(ΔX, 2);
    const ΔYSquare = pow(ΔY, 2);
    const ΔZSquare = pow(ΔZ, 2);

    const chordLength = sqrt(ΔXSquare + ΔYSquare + ΔZSquare);

    return chordLength;
}
```

***convert-degrees-to-radians.js:***

```
module.exports = function convertDegreesToRadians({ degrees }) {

    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
};
```

*This's following the Great-circle distance - From chord length, documented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Computational_formulas).*

Answer (score 1):

The answer from google

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/how-calculate-distances-map-maps-javascript-api

And the check from three part.

https://www.distancefromto.net/

```
static distance({ x: x1, y: y1 }, { x: x2, y: y2 }) {
    function toRadians(value) {
        return value * Math.PI / 180
    }

    var R = 6371.0710
    var rlat1 = toRadians(x1) // Convert degrees to radians
    var rlat2 = toRadians(x2) // Convert degrees to radians
    var difflat = rlat2 - rlat1 // Radian difference (latitudes)
    var difflon = toRadians(y2 - y1) // Radian difference (longitudes)
    return 2 * R * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(Math.sin(difflat / 2) * Math.sin(difflat / 2) + Math.cos(rlat1) * Math.cos(rlat2) * Math.sin(difflon / 2) * Math.sin(difflon / 2)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said before, your function is calculating a straight line distance to the destination point. If you want the driving distance/route, you can use [Google Maps Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix):

```
getDrivingDistanceBetweenTwoLatLong(origin, destination) {

 return new Observable(subscriber => {
  let service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [new google.maps.LatLng(origin.lat, origin.long)],
      destinations: [new google.maps.LatLng(destination.lat, destination.long)],
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, (response, status) => {
      if (status !== google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        console.log('Error:', status);
        subscriber.error({error: status, status: status});
      } else {
        console.log(response);
        try {
          let valueInMeters = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
          let valueInKms = valueInMeters / 1000;
          subscriber.next(valueInKms);
          subscriber.complete();
        }
       catch(error) {
        subscriber.error({error: error, status: status});
       }
      }
    });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I try to make the code a little bit understandable by naming the variables,
I hope this can help**

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(point1, point2) {

  const [lat1, lon1] = point1;
  const [lat2, lon2] = point2;
  const earthRadius = 6371;
  const dLat = convertDegToRad(lat2 - lat1);
  const dLon = convertDegToRad(lon2 - lon1);
  const squarehalfChordLength =
    Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(convertDegToRad(lat1)) * Math.cos(convertDegToRad(lat2)) *
    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);

  const angularDistance = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(squarehalfChordLength), Math.sqrt(1 - squarehalfChordLength));
  const distance = earthRadius * angularDistance;
  return distance;

}
```

Comment: ReferenceError: convertDegToRad is not defined

Comment: what phil said:

Comment: function convertDegToRad(value) {
        return value * Math.PI / 180
    }