# How do I identify whether I am belongs in specified radius with current latitude and longitude in IONIC 3?

Tags: ionic3

I am planning to develop a Hybrid App, where I need to allow the user to do certain action based on 100 radius within current latitude and longitude.

I don't what to keep on tracking user current location like what this link explains about https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/.

I need to allow the user if and only if the user within the specified radius.

Answer (score 0):

You can get distance between user location and your store location, then if distance is less then 100 then you can call function to enable service you want for user.

You can check below link to get code for distance calculation

[Function to calculate distance between two coordinates shows wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883601/function-to-calculate-distance-between-two-coordinates-shows-wrong)

Comment: Thanks @Kathrecha Krishna I will check with this and will update you

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ionic Native Geolocation Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/) to get user location using `getCurrentPosition()` then calculate distance between user and store and check if it's within the required radius or not.

The easiest way to calculate distance between two coordinates is by using [Ionic Native Google Maps Plugin](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/blob/master/documents/README.md). Use computeDistanceBetween(locationA, locationB) static method of the [Spherical](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/blob/master/documents/spherical/README.md) static class.

Comment: Thanks @Sherif Abdulmawla I will check with this and will update you.