# How can i get the closes address when comparing multiple addresses using google API in IONIC

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

i am using the following code to get distance between multiple address from a single location, after then i push the result to my html, which works fine...but i want to be able to get each distance for each user and also to display the closest users only.

```
data.forEach( (element) => {const distance = this.distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates(this.Senderlat,this.Senderlng,parseFloat(element.lat),parseFloat(element.lng));


        this.drivers.push(element);

    });
```

I am using this to display the loop in my html file, which works well..but i need to sort the data by a field name of distance or item.distance so that the closest person comes up first before orders

```
   <ion-item lines="none" *ngFor="let item of drivers>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883601/function-to-calculate-distance-between-two-coordinates - check this out.

Comment: Thanks for this..i am able to get the distance betweeen all the cordinates...but i need to display each distance in my html in order of the closest

Answer (score 0):

After you get the array of distances (in whatever unit)

```
distances.sort((dist1,dist2)=> dist2-dist1);
```

This takes care of sorting the original array.

```
<div *ngFor="let distance of distances; let i=index">
{{index}} {{distance}} <!-- prints the value from the sorted array-->
</div>
```

Comment: can u clarify pls..i am using like this to push to my html,             this.drivers.push(element);

Comment: In ionic UI iterate through the array and show it.

Comment: can u give an example pls..or u want me to paste i have tried?

Comment: Have added a sample code based on Angular