# Find the closest bar, when searching for a drink

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, geospatial, spatial-index

Problem: Find the closest bar that serves the drink(s) I'm looking for.

[image]

Here you can find the generated MySQL code http://pastebin.com/5Uc2ewUW

The API Request that interacts with this problem will have these parameters

```
query, String, ideally the drink name 
lng, double, the starting longitude
lat, double, the starting latitude
range, integer, max distance in meters (with a default value)
```

The query parameter may select more than one drink (think about searching for "Vodka").

What would be a good strategy to write a SQL query with good performance?

I'm not very expert, but my idea is to

- SELECT bars in the range
- SELECT from drink__bars where bar_id is in the previous select result
- JOIN the drinks table to get drinks data

How do I set the order based on the distance?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

**Edit**:Thanks for the answers till now, but they are mainly focused on calculate distance and that is covered. 
I don't get how to order result (that are drinks) based on the *distance* I have from bars.

Think like this meta query

```
SELECT drink.id, drink.name 
FROM $DATA_POOL
WHERE drink.name LIKE '%MY_QUERY%' 
ORDER BY $ORDER
```

where

- `$DATA_POOL` = a subset of drinks, that are server in the bars near me (I can already compute which bars are near me)
- `$ORDER` = the distance I have from the bar, based on the API params `lng` and `lat`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between 2 GPS coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates)

Comment: does @TheChaos  answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

ok, removed the old answer since it was not what you wanted...

is this more what you need?

```
SELECT
*,
@radius * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(( @startlat - abs(b.lat)) * pi() / 180 / 2),2) +
COS( @startlat * pi()/180) * COS(abs(b.lat) * pi() / 180) * POWER(SIN(( @startlng - b.lng) *
pi() / 180 / 2), 2) )) AS distance
FROM 
drinks d
JOIN drink_bars db ON (db.drink_id = d.id)
JOIN bars b ON (b.id_id = db.bar_id)
WHERE d.name LIKE '%mojito%'
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

So the query looks for a drink and all bars that have this drink and fetchs the data ordered by distance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is not really about how to compute distance from my starting lat/lng, I edited the question because it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

So you know how to calculate the distance, lets say we have a sub-query that does it.

All you need to do is to sort by distance like this:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name 
FROM 
 drinks d INNER JOIN
 drink_bars db ON db.drink_id = d.id INNER JOIN
 (SELECT id, <formula for distance> as distance FROM bars) b ON b.id = db.bar_id
WHERE d.name = @RequestedDrink AND b.distance < @MaxDistance
ORDER BY b.distance
```