# How to find radius between two points on google map api v2

Tags: math, trigonometry

I wanna draw circle between two points.Although I can draw a circle between two points ,I can not find the radius properly using pythagorean theorem.How can I find the radius of this circle?
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Not sure to understand your question: assuming that you can draw a circle between 2 points (as you write), how is it possible that you do not already have the corresponding radius? - Your question was maybe something else ?

Comment: I will choose two points and I will take latitute and longitude of them and I will find the center of these two points and I will draw a cicle which have the center I said before and this circle will have these two points.Sorry about bad English.Am I clear now ?

Comment: Ok that's to say you want the distance between the center coordinates and one of the two points to get the radius ? If so you might want to apply this kind of maths as described below, would it fit ?

[this so answer] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/365853/1720332)

Answer (score 0):

This is basic math. Coordinates are `( x1, y1 )` and `( x2, y2 )`.

Midpoint is:
`xm = ( x1 + x2 ) / 2` and
`ym = ( y1 + y2 ) / 2`

Distance is:
`dist = sqrt( ( x2 - x1 ) ^ 2 + ( y2 - y1 ) ^ 2 )`
(sqrt means square-root)

Radius is:
`r = dist / 2`