# how to calculate distance using gps Coordinates?

Tags: gps, coordinates

[image]

look at the picture above, see a black circle.

black circle Coordinates is lat(126.897453), lon(37.530028)

if the red rectangle is square(vertical and horizontal are 20m), I want to know the blue circle of coordinates

please let me know calculation formula.

In advance, thanks for your answer!

have a good time :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between 2 GPS coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates)

Comment: @JeremyP you don't understand this question!. I want to know that using one coordinate and distance to get other coordinate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is solved by first transforming the spherical lat/long coordinates to a cartesian x,y coordinates with unit meters.
Then you calculate the location with very basic addition. (x = x-20, y=y-20/2)
Then you transform the location back to lat/long coordinates.

Comment: thanks you for your answer. but i don't understand yet. do you mind if you do explain example to me.

Comment: Which part did you not understand? cartestian space?