# Calculating distance and speed using gps coordinates using qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, gps

I am attempting to convert the first code snippet at:

[Calculate distance between 2 GPS coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826)

```
//      var R = 6371; // km
//      var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
//      var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
//      var lat1 = lat1.toRad();
//      var lat2 = lat2.toRad();

//      var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
//              Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
//      var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
//      var d = R * c;
```

(also shown below) for use in qt c++. It is used in a program that simulates gps flight inside of a radio control simulator. The GpsCalcLoop grabs gps latitude and longitude (in decimal format) once per second. These are fed into my converted code in hopes of getting a distance traveled during that one second of time. Speed would then be calculated.

I used the information at this page:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtcore-qmath-h.html

to convert the math functions. The output, however, is not what I expected. No matter what is input into lat2, lat1, lon2, and lon1 the results are always the same, '16777200.00'.

I am hoping that someone more familiar with qt c++ will be able to show me where I have gone wrong with the conversion. or point me to where I can find qt c++ code that is working.

I will add that I have attempted to use "#include "<"QGeoPositionInfo">" but get a 'No such file or directory' error when running the program.

```
void TelemetrySimulator::onGpsCalcLoop()
 {

 if(rungps)
    {
    ui -> valuetest1 -> setValue(flat);
    ui -> valuetest2 -> setValue(flat2);
    ui -> valuetest3 -> setValue(flon);
    ui -> valuetest4 -> setValue(flon2);

    ui -> valuetest5 -> setValue(flat-flat2);
    ui -> valuetest6 -> setValue(flon-flon2);

    flat2 = flat;
    flon2 = flon;
    //--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826   //calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates--
    //      var R = 6371; // km
    //      var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
    //      var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
    //      var lat1 = lat1.toRad();
    //      var lat2 = lat2.toRad();

    //      var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    //              Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
    //      var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    //      var d = R * c;
    //--------------my conversio  to qt  c++---------
    //---converted to qt using this web page -> http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtcore-qmath-h.html----
    double R, dLat, dLon, lat1, lat2, lon2, lon1, a, c, d;

    lat2 = flat2;
    lat1 = flat;
    lon2 = flon2;
    lon1 = flon;

     R = 6371; // km
     dLat = qAcos(lat2-lat1); //dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad(); instead of qAcos could be qAsin, qAtan, qCos, qSin,
                                                       // qTan. All refer to Radials.
     dLon = qAcos(lon2-lon1); //dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
     lat1 = qAcos(lat1);  //lat1 = lat1.toRad();
     lat2 = qAcos(lat2);  //lat2 = lat2.toRad();

     a = qSin(dLat/2) * qSin(dLat/2) +  //Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
       qSin(dLon/2) * qSin(dLon/2) * qCos(lat1) * qCos(lat2);//Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) *  Math.cos(lat2);
     c = 2 * qAtan2(qSqrt(a), qSqrt(1-a)); //Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
     d = R * c;
     ui -> valuetest7 -> setValue(d);
     }

 }
```

---

Thanks to everyone for your great help! Here is the final code:

```
void MainWindow::onGpsCalcLoop()
{
    //Get initial values from gps run loop-------
     double lat2 = flat2;
     double lat1 = flat;
     double lon2 = flon2;
     double lon1 = flon;
     //GPS distance and speed calculation -------
     double dLat = .01745329 * (lat2 - lat1);
     double dLon = .01745329 * (lon2 - lon1);
     lat1 = .01745329 * lat1;
     lat2 = .01745329 * lat2;
     double a = qSin(dLat/2) * qSin(dLat/2) +
         qSin(dLon/2) * qSin(dLon/2) * qCos(lat1) * qCos(lat2);
     double c = 2 * qAtan2(qSqrt(a), qSqrt(1-a));
     double d = 3975 * c;
     //Distance calculation done. Next is total distance and speed------
     td = td + d;
     if (d > .1)
     {
         d = 0;
         td = 0;
     }
     if (ui -> metric -> isChecked())
     {
         ui -> valuetest1 -> setValue(td * 1.6);
         ui -> valuetest2 -> setValue((d * 3600) * 1.6);
     }
     else
     {
     ui -> valuetest1 -> setValue(td);
     ui -> valuetest2 -> setValue(d * 3600);
     }
     flat2 = flat;
     flon2 = flon;
}
```

I used .01745329*(whatever) instead of qDegreesToRadians(whatever) just to keep things as simple as possible.

Again, thanks to all for your help!

Comment: You're doing `setValue()` to ui in the beginning of the snippet. And where is the `getValue()`? Uninitialized variables, I think.

Comment: And: no-no, `toRad()` cannot be exchanged with `acos`, `asin` or other trigonomethric function. Use `qDegreesToRadians` http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmath.html#qDegreesToRadians

Comment: Log the values at each calculation step to narrow down the problem. As it is one can't see if the initial values are correct.

Comment: John West, the setValue() variables were set as global. Just to keep things constant I changed everything to global.

Comment: I changed acos to qdegreestoradians as you suggested, and, with other bug fixes, it seems to be working now. I compared the output to google earth, and my initial testing seems to be right on! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: llya, I logged my values as you suggested and it helped me find a bug. As I said above, it seems to be working now. Thank you!