# Query that finds all locations within a certain radius of a given coordinate

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial

My database has an `organisation` tables with two decimal columns `lat` and `lon` that indicate the location of the organisation. I'm trying to find all organisations within 800km of the coordinate `53.6771, -1.62958` (this roughly corresponds to Leeds in the UK).

The query I'm using is

```
select * 
from organisation 
where (3959 * acos(cos(radians(53.6771)) * 
      cos(radians(lat)) * 
      cos(radians(lon) - radians(-1.62958)) + sin(radians(53.6771)) * 
      sin(radians(lat)))) < 800
```

However this returns locations in Lyon, France which is about 970km from Leeds, UK. I realise that formulae such as the above make some simplifying assumptions (e.g. treating the shape of the Earth as a sphere), so I don't expect the results to be absolutely accurate, but I should be able to do better than this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using MySQL, but I can't change the definition of the `organisation` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a formula [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates) for calculating the distance in km between two points, and I have tried to convert it to mysql:

```
WHERE (6371 * 2 * 
ATAN2(
  SQRT(
    SIN(RADIANS((lat-53.6771)/2)) * SIN(RADIANS((lat-53.6771)/2)) + SIN(RADIANS((lon+1.62958)/2)) * SIN(RADIANS((lon+1.62958)/2)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(53.6771))
  ),
  SQRT(
    1-(SIN(RADIANS((lat-53.6771)/2)) * SIN(RADIANS((lat-53.6771)/2)) + SIN(RADIANS((lon+1.62958)/2)) * SIN(RADIANS((lon+1.62958)/2)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(53.6771)))
  )
)) < 800
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by using the multiplier for miles (3959) instead of kilometers (6371). The correct query is shown below

```
select * 
from   organisation 
where  (6371 * acos(cos(radians(53.6771)) * 
       cos(radians(lat)) * 
       cos(radians(lon) - radians(-1.62958)) + sin(radians(53.6771)) * 
       sin(radians(lat)))) < 800
```