# Error rates between Haversine and Vincenty

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, haversine, geodesic-sphere

I am comparing the effectiveness of Vincenty formulae and the haversine formula over varying distances of seperation . I would like to know the error rates between them. Is there any cool way to plot these ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you really want to compare great-circle distances with
geodesic distances.  Haversine and Vincenty happen to be algorithms for
computing such distances; however both result in excessive errors in
some limits.  See my answer to [Is the Haversine Formula or the
Vincenty's Formula better for calculating distance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248046/is-the-haversine-formula-or-the-vincentys-formula-better-for-calculating-distan/38663071#38663071).

I provide a better algorithm for geodesic distances in the Matlab
package [geographiclib](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50605).  This also provides accurate great circle
distances if the flattening of the ellipsoid is set to 0.  Here's a
simple illustration of its use plotting the relative and absolute error
for a random set of points.  This requires that my package be on your
Matlab path.

```
num = 100000;
lat1 = asind(2*rand(num,1)-1);
lat2 = asind(2*rand(num,1)-1);
lon1 = 180*(2*rand(num,1)-1);
lon2 = 180*(2*rand(num,1)-1);
wgs84 = defaultellipsoid;
a = wgs84(1);
b = a * (1 - ecc2flat(wgs84(2)));
sphere = [(2*a + b)/3, 0];
[s12s, azi1s, azi2s] = geoddistance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2, sphere);
[s12e, azi1e, azi2e] = geoddistance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2, wgs84);
erra = (s12s - s12e);
errr = 100 * erra ./ s12e;
figure(1); plot(s12e, abs(errr), 'x');
figure(2); plot(s12e, abs(erra), 'x');
```

You might also want to look at my answer to [How accurate is
approximating the Earth as a sphere?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25494/how-accurate-is-approximating-the-earth-as-a-sphere/63047#63047).