# Monitoring android GPS location

Tags: android, location

I am building an app that will monitor where a user is using GPS and alert him if he is within a certain distance of a particular place. I would provide the app with a list of the places and their latitude and longitude and the app would check against this list. Once the user has launched the app to start the location monitoring process, then most of the time he does not need to know anything about it and will be using other apps, making phone calls, or whatever. A user interface will only be displayed when the app finds a match with a location in the list.

I guess that this means that the location monitoring should run in background mode, but I am fairly new to android and I don't really understand about background processes or about location monitoring. Can anyone point me to a good tutorial or information?

Answer (score 0):

to building this app that will monitor where a user is using GPS and alert him if he is within a certain distance, you will using [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) in [background](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html) and using gps to get altitude and  longitude and you will using a [function to calculate a distance bitween a user location giving by gps and others location in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates) and you can also [start your Service on Boot Automatically](http://techblogon.com/android-start-service-on-boot/).

good luck.