# Calculate driving distance between two geolocation points

Tags: python-2.7, google-geolocation

Mind if I ask if any of you know how to calculate the actual driving distance between two points when latitude and longitude for both starting and destination points as input? Ps: with help of google API.

Comment: The answer is yes, we do mind.

Comment: [Calculate distance between 2 GPS coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates) The Python implementation is with you, if you still have questions after that then please ask here stating your problem

Comment: I wish to know the driving distance between two points but not the shortest distance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/