# Find user in specific radius or not in angular google map (agm)

Tags: angular, angular5

Input: Given a specific co-ordinate (latitude and longitude) and radius Output: Check user is in the circle or out of the circle?

How can I do this in angular google maps?

Comment: You can calculate the distance between 2 coordinates in any unit you want. And if that distance is smaller than your radius you can assume the user is within the radius. Look here for coordinate calculations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I will try out this...