# How to find the boundary coordinates of a google map by using center coordinates, width and height

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Say I have a center coordinate (1.22222, 2.3333) and width 25 km and height 12 km.
From this I want to find the boundary points with specified center

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between 2 GPS coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates)

Answer (score 1):

On option is to use the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) [computeOffset method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#spherical.computeOffset).

```
var height = 12000; // m
var width = 25000; // m
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(1.22222, 2.3333);
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var top = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, height / 2, 0);
var bottom = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, height / 2, 180);
var left = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, width / 2, -90);
var right = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, width / 2, 90);
bounds.extend(top);
bounds.extend(left);
bounds.extend(bottom);
bounds.extend(right);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/72rfv8ex/2/)

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var height = 12000; // m
    var width = 25000; // m
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(1.22222, 2.3333);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var top = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, height / 2, 0);
    var bottom = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, height / 2, 180);
    var left = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, width / 2, -90);
    var right = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, width / 2, 90);
    bounds.extend(top);
    bounds.extend(left);
    bounds.extend(bottom);
    bounds.extend(right);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: center,
      zoom: 2,
      mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });
    var centerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: center
    })
    var rect = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      map: map,
      bounds: bounds
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
</script>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key= 
AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: How can I set the above as map boundary and go to the zoom level to make this as the boundary?

Comment: That sounds like a different question (you need to dynamically size your map div to make that happen)