# How to import geolib in React Native to calculate the distance between two points?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to calculate the distance between Longitude and Latitude in react native. I have the Longitude and Latitude of my current location and I have the Longitude and Latitude of my destination. Is their any easy way to calculate the distance?

I tried using geolib, but keep getting an error. Below is what I did:

```
npm i geolib
```

I put the geolib in my import statement too.

```
  import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    FlatList,
    Text,
    View,
    Alert,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Linking,
    Image,
    ScrollView,
    RefreshControl,
    Location,
    geolib
  } from 'react-native';

 _renderItem = ({item, index}) => {

    var dist  = geolib.getDistance(
      this.state.latitude,
      this.state.longitude,
      item.LatL,
      item.Long2
    );

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
        <Text>Latitude from file:{item.LatL}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude from file :{item.Long2} </Text>
        <Text style={styles.AddressSpace} >Miles:{dist }</Text>
      </View>
    );
```

Below is the error that I am getting:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object
>     (evaluating '_reactNative.geolib.getDistance')

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am getting this error as soon as I put this code:

```
   const dist = geolib.getDistance(
      { latitude, longitude },{ latitude: item.LatL, longitude: item.Long2 }
    );
```

[image]

Not sure, but I am still getting the above error: Below is my entire code:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, item } from 'react-native';
import geolib from 'geolib';
class ServiceListDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { latitude, longitude } = this.state;

    const dist = geolib.getDistance(
  { latitude, longitude },
  { latitude: 33.935558, longitude: -117.284912 }
);
    return (
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
        <Text>Miles:{dist} </Text>
        {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default ServiceListDetails;

_  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VadZ.png
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between 2 GPS coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates)

Comment: Above answer is not in React Native.

Comment: none of the above answers are in react native. I checked before posting my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`geolib` doesn't exist as a named export in `react-native`.

```
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  Text,
  View,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Linking,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  RefreshControl,
  Location
  // Remove `geolib` from here.
} from 'react-native';

// Import the lib from the one you've just installed.
import geolib from 'geolib';
```

It helps to know how the [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) works in ES6 to be able to use all the libs you want and structure your own code in independent module files.

Then, to get the distance between two points with Geolib, you need to use the [`getDistance` function](https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib#geolibgetdistanceobject-start-object-end-int-accuracy-int-precision), which takes 2 objects as parameters.

```
// Function signature from the documentation:
geolib.getDistance(object start, object end[, int accuracy, int precision])
```

In your case:

```
// Using destructuring here just to avoid repetition.
const { latitude, longitude } = this.state;

const dist = geolib.getDistance(
  { latitude, longitude },
  { latitude: item.LatL, longitude: item.Long2 }
);
```

Also note that:

> Return value is always float and represents the distance in meters.

To convert it to miles, you could multiply the result by `0.000621`.

```
<Text style={styles.AddressSpace}>Miles: {dist * 0.000621}</Text>
```

*Ideally, I would put the `0.000621` [magic number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882/1218980) inside a clearly defined constant somewhere.*

Or just use the [`geolib.convertUnit` function](https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib#geolibconvertunitstring-unit-float-distance-int-round).

```
<Text style={styles.AddressSpace}>Miles: {geolib.convertUnit('mi', dist)}</Text>
```

Comment: I am getting the above error: TypeError: null is not an object. I pasted the phone picture above. Is it possible that Longitude and latitude are becoming null.

Comment: @Anjali notice the destructuring I'm doing with `this.state`.

Comment: Hi Emile, Not sure what am I doing wrong, but I am still getting the above error TypeError: null is not an object. I pasted my code above at the end of my post. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Anjali maybe you're passing null somewhere as a long or lat, I don't know, I'm not using either geolib nor your code. It's now your job to debug and see what's going on. You're already on the right track since now the error comes from Geolib.

Comment: I put the code of my entire page. Still getting the error. Can you please look at the code. As soon as I remove the line    const dist = geolib.getDistance(
  { latitude, longitude },
  { latitude: 33.935558, longitude: -117.284912 }
); error stops coming.

Comment: Finally, figured out what I was doing wrong. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import { getDistance } from "geolib"
```

and then using:

```
const dist = getDistance(...)
```

I had a similar issue with computeDestinationPoint(...)