# Chain two geospatial queries with different coordinates

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geospatial, nestjs

I use Mongo with Mongoose. I have two coordinates points. I want to find users in a specific circle (with the first coordinates point as center). Then, for each users found, I want to calculate the distance from the second point.

How can I do this ? I can do one geospatial query, but two...

Ty by advance !

Comment: afaik, mongodb only supports returning the distances for found documents from the search point. instead of having to do a query per user, simply calculate the distances you need client-side, with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/365853/4368485).

Comment: Ty for your response !
That's what I did, I use leaflet so I used "distanceTo" method.
Ty again !