# Writing javascript to detect speed

Tags: javascript

I am a new member. For school, they want us to write code to figure out the speed of the device (when driving). Is this possible in javascript? Im assuming it will be challenging but any ideas help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's a location API that you should be able to use to get the user's GPS coords. Use that + Date() you can calculate the speed. The user will have to consent to location access and will probably need to keep the webpage open for you to poll their coords.
Oh...and to Klaycon's point... I was assuming a browser, but this will be different if you're running Node or Deno or something. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Comment: Hypothetically, if the browser has access to geolocation, then by getting the timestamp and the location, one can calculate haversine_distance between the two locations, which, divide by the time, should give you speed. As for how, I leave that up to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) to get current position.

Since speed is distance over time, you can use a [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to periodically get the position (every 3 seconds for example) and [calculate the distance between the last and current coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates).

Since that's a homework/school work, I think I shouldn't give you any code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was your homework and I should not be giving you direct answers for you to copy and paste in but your question was years ago so I will provide my most in-depth copy-and-paste answer...
In the code, I have put some comments with fairly nice explanations if you care to read them this does use a default thingy to get the speed i thought of doing the math myself but I think letting the browser do it for you is still widely supported with different browsers and much easier.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>SPEED</title>
    <script>
        function getAccel() {
            // Display a loading message while attempting to get accelerometer data
            document.write("loading...");

            if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
                // Inform the user that their device supports geolocation, but there might be issues with the code
                document.body.innerHTML =
                    "Your device can find location but the code could be doing some funky things";

                function success(position) {
                    // Extract latitude, longitude, and speed from the geolocation data
                    lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    long = position.coords.longitude;
                    speed = position.coords.speed * 2.236936;

                    // Display the speed, longitude, and latitude on the webpage
                    document.body.innerHTML =
                        speed +
                        " MPH" +
                        "<br>Longitude: " +
                        long +
                        " -<br>Latitude: " +
                        lat +
                        " | ";
                }

                function error() {
                    // If permission is not granted, fetch location based on IP address using a third-party API
                    fetch("https://json.geoiplookup.io")
                        .then((res) => res.text())
                        .then((data) => {
                            var ip = JSON.parse(data);
                            // Display location based on IP address if precise location or speed permission is not granted
                            document.body.innerHTML =
                                "You did not grant permission for the script to get your precise location or speed<br>Your location based on your IP is Longitude: " +
                                ip.longitude +
                                " Latitude: " +
                                ip.latitude;
                        });
                }

                // Set options for geolocation, such as enabling high accuracy and setting a timeout
                const options = {
                    enableHighAccuracy: true,
                    maximumAge: 30000,
                    timeout: 1,
                };

                // Watch for changes in the device's position and call success or error accordingly
                const watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
                    success,
                    error,
                    options
                );
            } else {
                // Inform the user that their device cannot track location
                document.body.innerHTML =
                    "Your device cannot track location...<br>We're out of luck :/";
            }
        }

        window.onload = () => {
            // Call getAccel function when the window loads to initiate the process
            
            getAccel();
            
            // Autoclick the button to request accelerometer permissions, just in case permissions are already granted
            document.getElementById("accelPermsButton").click();
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: lightblue">
    <div id="main">
        <!-- Button to initiate the process of getting accelerometer permissions -->
        <button id="accelPermsButton" onclick="getAccel()" style="
          position: fixed;
          font-size: max(2.5vh, 6.5vw);
          height: min(100vh, 100vw);
          width: min(100vh, 100vw);
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        ">
            Click or tap to get accelerometer permissions.
        </button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```