# How do i convert GPS coordinates in decimal place to kilometers? I am trying write a function that does this

Tags: function, latitude-longitude

For Example lets say I have 2 coordinates (lat:7.xxxxx and Long:3.xxxx) and (lat:8.xxxxx and long:5.xxxxx)
I want to tell the distance between the 2 points in kilometers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate distance between 2 GPS coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula