# Best way/workflow/logic to detect when a vehicle is stationary

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-table-storage, azure-maps

I am currently uploading the gps positions of some vehicles to the azure tables. I was wondering what the best logic was and what component (if any) can help me determine when a vehicle is stationary.

I have seen that with Azure Maps I can deduce if the vehicle is within a specific area. Can I introduce other logics? o Can I use other tools in the Azure universe?

Answer (score 0):

this is not related / restricted to Azure services, but rather it's pure logic. I guess you just need to compare geolocations given some interval.

[Calculate distance between 2 GPS coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates)